# Will my Surface 3 work with no battery installed?

Tags: microsoft-surface

I have a surface 3 and the battery has swollen causing g the screen to bulge if I remove the battery will it work from power supply cable without battery I installed

Comment: I've seen many people with actual battery faults (0%) still working on a machine exactly as you describe. If the power goes away though, so does your work. Not an answer because I've only seen other posts, not done it myself.

Comment: FWIW If you remove the battery, the screen will still be deformed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.

I have seen many laptops be used without a battery and they work fine. I have even seen them without screens as well! But as @spikey_richie said, you will probably deform the laptop, and create problems for the laptop in the future. It is not a good idea to leave a laptop designed with a battery to have no battery. It was designed to have it in there.

Answer (score 0):

Surface 3 should not boot without a battery installed.

Since the screen has to be removed for battery replacement, it might actually help if the old battery has made the screen come off from the sides.